# gsoap client call blocks when the server is not available

Tags: soap, gsoap

I am looking for a method to detect if the gsoap web service is available.
Unfortunately when the service is offline then the client gsoap calls block
for a long time. Setting the soap.recv_timeout and the soap.send_timeout to 
zero do not help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a bit late, but I finally found (what I think is) a better answer by skulking through the source code (why they don't document this, I don't know):

Look for "soap.connect_timeout".  When I set this to 3, it times-out after 3 seconds as expected when the web service is unavailable.

The above recv_timeout and send_timeout didn't work for me in the case of "service unavailable".

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure that by setting soap.recv_timeout and soap.send_timeout with 0 means NO TIMEOUT. Try set this variables with 1 (1 means 1 second).

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for a solution to the same problem and recognized the erroneous part about setting recv_timeout to 0, but I had set it to 20 and still got no timeout, so I followed the second post and used connect_timeout, which did work as I intended.